# python3 binary in /usr/local/bin but also…not?

Tags: filesystems, symlink, macos

I don't understand what's happening here. I'm on Mac.
When I run `/usr/local/bin/python3` or `/usr/local/bin/python3.8`, I get a `No such file or directory` error. Any ideas what could be going on here?

Output of ls -l:

```
-rwxr-xr-x   1  admin    246 Oct 24  2019 ipython3
lrwxr-xr-x   1  admin    38 Aug 11 17:25 python3 -> ../Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/bin/python3
lrwxr-xr-x   1  admin    45 Aug 11 17:25 python3-config -> ../Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/bin/python3-config
lrwxr-xr-x   1  admin    40 Aug 11 17:25 python3.8 -> ../Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/bin/python3.8
lrwxr-xr-x   1  admin    47 Aug 11 17:25 python3.8-config -> ../Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/bin/python3.8-config
```

Comment: If you have the which command in macos, try `which python3` to see which file is being used, this probably will show you some different location where python was installed. Also it is important how you have installed python, using your package manager, manually, from source, etc.

Comment: @thanasisp Thanks.  `which python3` indicates it's being run from my miniconda3 directory.  That I knew.  The question I have is why I can't specify the absolute path to a different `python3`.  I assume it's a problem with the symlinking Homebrew package manager does?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely those symlinks point to files that don't exit.  Possibly Homebrew upgraded Python to 3.8.6 but didn't update the symlinks for some reason.

To fix, try:

```
brew unlink python@3.8 && brew link python@3.8
```

If that doesn't fix it, try:

```
brew reinstall python@3.8
```